# How to convert JQuery AJAX function to vue.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, vue.js

I have the following AJAX function written in jQuery (just make AJAX call to get outcome for div A and div B - the example is simplified)

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#c" ).on( "click", function() {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "post.php",
            data: "",
            dataType:"JSON",
            success: function(data){
                if (data.status == 1){
                    $("#a").html(data.a);
                    $("#b").html(data.b);
                }
            }
        })
    })
})
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="a"></div>
<div id="b"></div>
<button id="c">Start</button>
```

I understand how to make the HTML template for vue.js and how to set JavaScript variables, but how do I to set AJAX request for vue.js?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Well, first thing first, you have to get rid of DOM Targeting with jQuery.In VueJS, there are no direct DOM manipulation.
Next, you have to stop thinking jQuery way - Vue and jQuery are 2 totally different things which have different design pattern.

About your problem:

First you have to attach event listener on DOM Element

```
<button id="c" @click="ajaxMethod">Start</div>
```

Then into your Vue instance, you want to define that method, but before you make it, make sure you have jQuery installed

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
   msg: 'hi';
  },
  methods: {
   ajaxMethod() {
    jQuery.ajax({
      // bla bla bla...
    })
   }
  }
})
```

But at the end, I won't to suggest you use jQuery here - there are much better libs such as Vue Resource and Axios.

Comment: +1 for pointing the difference between the data centric logic of Vue and the DOM manipulating approach of JQuery

Answer (score 1):

The suggested way is to use the axios library.

```
<div id="app">  
  <div>{{a}}</div>
  <div>{{b}}</div>
  <button @click="retrieveData">Start</button>
</div>
```

Where the Vue instance is

```
import axios from 'axios'
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    a: '',
    b: ''
  },
  methods: {
    retrieveData() {
      axios.post('post.php', {}, )
       .then(resp => {
         this.a = resp.data.a
         this.b = resp.data.b
       })
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for the answer, is the Axios library a part of vue.js or must be loaded separately?

Comment: Testing now, I get the following error: 
          SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module

Comment: Make the import declaration appear at the top of the file

Comment: How is different from using jQuery inside retrieveData method?

Comment: Simple: no jQuery required, kb upon kb saved.

Comment: Robo Robok - yes, in case you load jQuery as such on your site, then it does not make sense to use another library for AJAX. Even this is simplified example so if you use jQuery AJAX then you can add the values in DOM per jQuery. But I have asked which way is the best (even it is subjective) when using vue.js.  gurhet - I have added the import declaration appear at the top of the file but even I still get the error :-(

Comment: It depend on the environment you are using import it the same way you imported jquery

Comment: gurghet - now I understand, thank you very much (sorry for writing incorrect your nickname in previous post, cannot be edited more)

Comment: No worries please accept and upvote what you find useful